# Alert message when program in background [Titanium]

Tags: iphone, android, titanium

I'm making count down timer for iPhone and Android. The problem is alert message. When I close the app , program is not working and alert can't show. So, I think ... I should add in iCal and it will alert but I don't know how to make with Titanium and

how to make schedule task or alert message in Titanium for iPhone and Android ?

Comment: I want to show alert message when program in background

Comment: My point is that your question is about two different system/platform.

Comment: yes ... I'm using titanium for two platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alerts for background applications are called Push Notifications. Please refer to the corresponding article:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576

Comment: push notification need internet connection. I want to use my app offline.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/107431/alert-message-on-background